# Validate css.php with $_get vars?

Tags: php, css, validation, w3c

I am using php to generate a css file, declaring a header like:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8"); 
?>
```

and passing the url from index.php like:

```
<link href="http://www.site.com/css.php?style_profile=2" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I can't get this file to validate from the w3c css validator because it doesn't recognize the file type. This is the error I keep getting:

```
Unknown error org.w3c.www.http.HttpInvalidValueException: Invalid content type.
```

Is there any way to get this to validate without manually pasting the css data? If not, is there any other validation service that will recognize a css.php file (or one with get vars attached, if that is the issue causing the error)? I'd really like to be able to validate by link and not have to cut and paste the css for every single page on my site.

Comment: I was thinking maybe adding a rewrite rule to apache to trick it into thinking it's a css file or something, but I'd like to get some feedback from someone familiar with the issue if possible before I go tinkering with .htaccess just to validate the css.

Comment: Have you tried turning on error_reporting(E_ALL) in PHP and seeing if it outputs anything? If @MrSlayer's answer doesn't do it, then it's probably because you are sending the header after you've started output of the body (which would show up in the errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this will resolve your problem (unable to test right now), but it is something that I noticed:

[According to the W3 spec](http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset.en.php), your PHP header is incorrect, and it should read `charset=utf-8`.

Comment: Correct, you must use charset=